# Error thrown when set constraint.isActive = true

Tags: swift, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have a scrollView and I'm adding a textView inside it. I want to centre the text view to the schollView. The code throws an error on the line `textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`, but only when I call `.isActive = true` as well.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textView = UITextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 1000))
    textView = text
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.sizeToFit()
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false

    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And what error exactly is thrown? Do you mind sharing it?

Comment: @Larme the error was a SIGABRT. I’m not sure how much that helps :(

Comment: Full error message? Is scrollView nil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add it

```
scrollView.addSubview(textView)
textView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

before setting constraints , also if you set constraints of scrollview inside IB , then don't set

```
// comment scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```